# conditional sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, articles

> 1. The Earth revolves around the Sun.

I consider the above statement should be written without any article as we're using earth and sun as a proper noun. Which of these is correct to write?

> 2. Earth revolves around Sun.

**OR**

> 3. Earth revolves around the Sun.

Comment: These questions are not related to each other and should be asked separately.

Comment: As for the use of articles with such words as *earth, moon, sun* you can find lots of info at [About definite article before "Earth", "Moon" and "Sun"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/about-definite-article-before-earth-moon-and-sun)

Comment: Why do you say conditional??

Answer (score 1):

[This discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/about-definite-article-before-earth-moon-and-sun) provides very good information about how to use articles in your context.

Since both "Earth" and "Sun" are to be treated as specific / specified celestial bodies, the definite article is needed. Therefore, the most correct is:

> 1. **The** Earth revolves around **the** Sun.